# How to align the labels of sankey diagram?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, sankey-diagram

In this example, when some of the values are the same (e.g. 0), the labels are getting overlapped. Can someone help me align these labels vertically? I want them to be moved to the top of the node/bar.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Oil', 'Transportation', 94],
            ['Natural Gas', 'Transportation', 3],
            ['Coal', 'Transportation', 0],
            ['Renewable', 'Transportation', 0],
            ['Nuclear', 'Transportation', 3],

            ['Oil', 'Industrial', 0],
            ['Natural Gas', 'Industrial', 0],
            ['Coal', 'Industrial',0],
            ['Renewable', 'Industrial', 0],
            ['Nuclear', 'Industrial',0],

            ['Oil', 'Residential & Commercial', 0],
            ['Natural Gas', 'Residential & Commercial', 0],
            ['Coal', 'Residential & Commercial',0],
            ['Renewable', 'Residential & Commercial', 0],
            ['Nuclear', 'Residential & Commercial', 0],

            ['Oil', 'Electric Power', 0],
            ['Natural Gas', 'Electric Power', 0],
            ['Coal', 'Electric Power', 0],
            ['Renewable', 'Electric Power', 0],
            ['Nuclear', 'Electric Power', 0]
        ],
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Energy in the United States'
    }]

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmn6gjby/3/

Comment: Is it enough for you to set dataLabels.padding to -5?
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x7ufycos/

Comment: @raf18seb the padding option is moving the labels horizontally, I want a considerable amount of gap between the labels vertically.

Comment: What about to position every label manually in CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nts1c2uo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return every label as HTML element:

```
plotOptions: {
  sankey: {
    dataLabels: {
      useHTML: true,
      nodeFormatter: function() {
        return "<span class='labelPosition label-" + this.colorIndex + "'>" + this.key + "</span>"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

set `position: relative;` and position every label manually in CSS:

```
.labelPosition {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.label-0 {
  top: 0px;
}

.label-5 {
  top: 6px;
}

.label-6 {
  top: -1px;
}

.label-7 {
  top: 2px;
}

.label-8 {
  top: 12px;
}
```

Online demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jbtLuygc/)